# Imageview and recycleview inside scrollview with background

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

In my layout the recycle view is scrolling but image is static what I want is when user scrolls the image also scroll along with recycle view please help me out..!!
I have omitted id's with blank spaces
I've tries scroll view > relative layout/Linear layout>(imageview+recycle view) but it crashes the application.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="      "
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context="      "

    >


    <ru.egslava.blurredview.BlurredImageView
        app:radius="0.8"
        app:keepOriginal="true"
        app:downSampling="2"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="    "

        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:id="       "
        />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="      "
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_below="      "
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        >
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: add your image as header of your RecyclerView.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29449329/recyclerview-with-scrolling-background check this out. Its similar to your question

Answer (score 1):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="your image"/>

         <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="your image"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list_recylclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

and in Java code make  `mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`
to scroll correctly credits [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42388743/5235032)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this tutorial, this is what you[enter link description here](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/)

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/love_music"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/backdrop_title"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/backdrop_title" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/backdrop_subtitle"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/backdrop_subtitle" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```